# Hyperledger fabric: Error: chaincode argument error: json: cannot unmarshal array into Go struct field strArgs.Args of type string

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric

I'm trying to create a simple database table using Hyperledger fabric. The table has 3 fields, ID, name and date of birth. Name and date of birth is string. I'm using the basic-network example. Here is my chaincode:

```
const shim = require('fabric-shim');
const util = require('util');

var Chaincode = class {

  // Initialize the chaincode
  async Init(stub) {
    console.info('========= example02 Init =========');
    console.log("HELLO WORLD!!!");
    console.log("Init: Does nothing!");
    return shim.success();
  }

  async Invoke(stub) {
    let ret = stub.getFunctionAndParameters();
    console.info("Truong: async Invoke!!");
    console.info(ret);
    let method = this[ret.fcn];
    if (!method) {
      console.log('no method of name:' + ret.fcn + ' found');
      return shim.success();
    }
    try {
      let payload = await method(stub, ret.params);
      return shim.success(payload);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return shim.error(err);
    }
  }

  // Insert
  async insert(stub, args) {
    console.log("Truong: async insert!!!");
    if (args.length != 2) {
      throw new Error('Incorrect number of arguments. Expecting 2');
    }

    let ID = args[0];
    let Attrs = args[1];
    await stub.putState(ID, Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(Attrs)));
  }

  // Delete
  async delete(stub, args) {
    console.info("Truong: async delete!!!");
    if (args.length != 1) {
      throw new Error('Incorrect number of arguments. Expecting 1');
    }

    let ID = args[0];

    // Delete the key from the state in ledger
    await stub.deleteState(ID);
  }

  // query callback representing the query of a chaincode
  async query(stub, args) {
    if (args.length != 1) {
      throw new Error('Incorrect number of arguments. Expecting name of the person to query')
    }

    let jsonResp = {};
    let ID = args[0];

    // Get the state from the ledger
    let Result = await stub.getState(A);
    if (!Result) {
      jsonResp.error = 'Failed to get state for ' + ID;
      throw new Error(JSON.stringify(jsonResp));
    }

    jsonResp.ID = ID;
    jsonResp.Attrs = Result.toString();
    console.info('Query Response:');
    console.info(jsonResp);
    return Result;
  }
};

shim.start(new Chaincode());
```

However when I type the following line:

```
docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp" peer0.org1.example.com peer chaincode query -C mychannel -n mycc -c '{"Args":["insert", "1", {"name": "Dang Manh Truong", "date": "26/04/1995"}]}'
```

There was an error:

```
Error: chaincode argument error: json: cannot unmarshal array into Go struct field strArgs.Args of type string
```

Does it mean that fabric does not accept json as an input? Please help me, thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Args` must be an array of strings.  You will need to escape the JSON content:

`"{\"name\": \"Dang Manh Truong\", \"date\": \"26\/04\/1995\"}"`

`peer ... -c '{"Args":["insert", "1","{\"name\": \"Dang Manh Truong\", \"date\": \"26\/04\/1995\"}" ]}'`