# passing arguments for chaincode invocation as bytes

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

When invoking a chaincode, there is the -c option for passing arguments. As far as I have understood (see also [Hyperledger fabric: Error: chaincode argument error: json: cannot unmarshal array into Go struct field strArgs.Args of type string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54157356/hyperledger-fabric-error-chaincode-argument-error-json-cannot-unmarshal-arra)), these arguments need to be passed as string array.
For example:

```
-c '{"Args":["add", "peter", "6"]}'
```

There is a the `GetArgs()`function (https://godoc.org/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim#ChaincodeStub.GetArgs) which returns the arguments as an array of byte arrays. 
In the above case this means that the third argument ("6") is returned as a byte array of length 1 with 54 as first entry.
But I would like to represent the third argument ("6") in a byte array of length 1 with 6 (00000110) as first entry.
Isn't it possible at all to pass bytes/numeric types as arguments?

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is to pass third argument as an json and unmarshal it from string in your chaincode.

```
    '{"Args": ["add", "peter", "[6]"]}'
```

and then something like

```
    var arr []byte
    err := json.Unmarshal(args[2], &arr) // args[2] is the third argument from the list
    fmt.Println(arr)
```